# Element won't move across

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a form but when I try to centralise it, it just stay tight to the left side of #wrapper. It reacts to margin-top but not anything to do with going across. I've tried putting a value on margin, using margin-left and still nothing. I'm pretty sure I've followed the YouTube tutorial I'm working with character for character so not sure where I've gone wrong, does anybody have any ideas?

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 1000px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin: 0px auto;
  min-height: 400px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #999;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#formDiv {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Registration Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="formDiv"></div>
    <form method="POST" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <label>First Name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="fname" /> <br/><br/>
      <label>Last Name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="lname" /> <br/><br/>
      <label>Email:</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="email" /> <br/><br/>
      <label>Password:</label><br>
      <input type="password" name="password" /> <br/><br/>
      <label>Image:</label><br>
      <input type="file" name="image" /> <br/><br/>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You closed your formdiv tag to early.  Use this:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Registration Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

    <div id="formDiv">

    <form method="POST" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <label>First Name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="fname" /> <br/><br/>

    <label>Last Name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="lname" /> <br/><br/>

    <label>Email:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="email" /> <br/><br/>

    <label>Password:</label><br>
    <input type="password" name="password" /> <br/><br/>

    <label>Image:</label><br>
    <input type="file" name="image" /> <br/><br/>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" /> 

    </form>


    </div>


</div>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to center it, you also need to center *form* element

```
#wrapper form{
      width: 180px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/47ku1qud/

Comment: Glad it helped. If it solved your problem can you validate the answer as correct, if you don't mind.